# Convertir objeto String en un objeto XML en javaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, javascript-objeto

me encuentro con un problema, tengo un objeto que tiene atributos de un XML
pero lo tengo todo en una cadena String y lo que quiero es convertir esa cadena en un
objeto XML para poder llamar esos atributos y mostrarlos en una tabla.
Adjunto la imagen de como me trae los datos y como se visualiza en el front [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quizas esta respuesta te pueda servir. Hay varias maneras la respuesta a la pregunta es amplia (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059224/which-is-the-best-library-for-xml-parsing-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del navegador es simple `var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(tuCadenaString, 'application/xml')`, entonces tienes un documento DOM XML y puedes utilizar el W3C DOM y XPath 1.0 para atravesarlo.